# how to turn stored String containing logic in to executable in SCALA/JAVA at run time

Tags: java, scala

Is there a way to turn stored String containing logic in to executable in SCALA/JAVA at run time?

Trying to solve a problem where rules are present in an XML, which can change frequently. I need to read the rules from XML and process it on a dataset like as below

```
if ((var="abc" AND var1="1") AND check_value(parm1, parm2) > 0)
result = "found it"
else
if ((var="abc" AND var1="1") AND check_value(parm1, parm2) < 0)
result = "Not Found"
```

*check_value is a function. Logic will be defined in code.

Since xml will be changing frequently i want to avoid changing code everytime.

Comment: What does check_value return?

Comment: It looks like you have to develop an interpreter. Perhaps you may be interested in parser combinators: https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Parser+Combinators--Getting+Started After parsing you can take the structured representation of your "program" and evaluate according to the rules you were talking about.

Comment: check_value returns Integer value

Comment: You have also great possibilities to work with xml in scala. http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-xml-examples-xml-literals-source-code-searching-xpath

Comment: It seems like you are not a very experienced programmer and you are asking about your idea for how to do something instead of asking about what you are trying to do. It's possible that generating an executable (you mean a class file?) isn't the right way of solving this problem. Try to rephrase the question in terms of what you are actually trying to do, and include more details so we can better help you.